# How to create a rectangle shape in cocos2d-android

Tags: cocos2d

I am new to cocos2d-android. I want to create a rectangle shape in the scene .for that i am trying to do something like this.

```
  CGRect rect = CGRect.make(x,y,70,70);
```

But it was not displaying the rectangle so far. could any one help me to do so?

Comment: Work through [a basic tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/33750/cocos2d-x-tutorial-for-ios-and-android-getting-started) first. With that you'll be able to ensure you have everything set up correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [the example file](https://code.google.com/p/cocos2d-android/source/browse/trunk/src/org/cocos2d/tests/DrawPrimitivesTest.java?r=100) for drawing primitives. You can see an example of drawing a arbitrary polygon there:

```
// closed purple poly
gl.glColor4f(1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
gl.glLineWidth(2);
CCPoint vertices2[] = {CCPoint.ccp(30, 130), CCPoint.ccp(30, 230), CCPoint.ccp(50, 200)};
Primitives.drawPoly(gl, vertices2, 3, true);
```

Just define your rectangle points there.

There are a lot more [test examples](https://code.google.com/p/cocos2d-android/source/browse/?r=100#svn/trunk/src/org/cocos2d/tests%253Fstate%253Dclosed) to be found there that can answer the basic drawing questions like this.